# Wordpress 301 redirect. Page no longer displaying

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

Need a little help. Not sure what has happened here, and dont really know where to start looking to fix this issue

I working on a new site for a friend

ndatraining.co.uk/v2/

This has been working fine Until today.

if you click on any of the links in the main Nav the pages no longer load, you end up on the current site with a 404

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have any issue with WordPress Urls going 404, if something was working before but not now , like in your case.

First thing you should try is to go to Settings > Permalinks ...It will refresh your rules and most of the time, temporary issues regarding 404  will be resolved.